# Beyond Compare - how to ignore readonly flag for TFS files when comparing

Tags: tfs, readonly, beyondcompare

I am trying to use Beyond Compare to compare files that have read only flags (caused from TFS)
to a directory of files that should be identical other than the readonly flag.

Is there a Beyond Compare setting that will ignore the readonly flag.  I realize I could manually clear the readonly flag via windows but this but this is time consuming/etc.

Beyond Compare Version 3.2.4 (build 13298)
TFS 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By read only flags, do you mean the DOS read only attribute (like system, hidden, archive)?  Beyond Compare already ignores those by default.

Use the **Session->Session Settings...** menu item to open the comparison preferences dialog.  On the **Comparison** tab make sure that **Read-only** is unchecked under **Compare file attributes**.  If there are also differences in the last modified times of the files you should turn on the **Compare contents** checkbox too.